# How do I add audio files to my resources correctly in Visual Studios 2022?

Tags: vb.net, wav

I am getting this error message when trying to use a audio(WAV) file in my VS 2022 project.

Error   BC30456 'chicken' is not a member of 'Random_Images_for_VS_2017.My.Resources'.

The code is: My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.chicken, AudioPlayMode.Background)

I can clearly see that chicken.wav is in my Resource folder and I have another WAV file that works fine with no error, so I do not understand why it won't recognize it.  I haven't used VS for awhile so maybe I am just forgetting something.

Thanks!

I tried researching on my own and using the Help but I didn't find much in my own search.

Comment: What did you actually do? Did you just add the file to the folder or did you actually add a resource? That folder is merely the source for your resources. If you haven't actually added a resource then that file will simply ne ignored. Open the Resources page of the project properties. You ought to be able to work out what to do from there. Delete the file from the folder first, otherwise there will be a conflict when VS tries to add it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happened.  Thank you for your response!